# Two children to a border

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created a border and inside it I put a combox. After that, I also added a checkbox but then VS complained that there's only one child property allowed. It's possible that I'm asking the wrong question.

Should I use a different control for "keeping stuff together"? Which one would that be?

If the border is correct for the purpose, what am I doing incorrectly, then?

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" ... >
  <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" ... />
  <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" ... />
</Border>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Border` is a fine control to use if you *want* a border around your content, but its not a `Panel`, so it can only have one child. Simply do something like:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" ... >
  <StackPanel>
     <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" ... />
     <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" ... />
  </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Now the `Border` only has one child, and your other elements are laid out by a `Panel` element which *can* have multiple children.

Comment: Oh, I've tried that but I was mislead by the fact that my controls that I put **onto** the panel were not positioned the same way they are if I put them directly in the frame. Am I correct in my guess that I need to put some layouting component as a child to the *StackPanel* control?

Comment: @KonradViltersten `StackPanel` will give you a very specific layout, and may not be the `Panel` you are looking for. What layout are you trying to get? You shouldn't need to *add* another panel, just use a different one.

Comment: Not sure on the name of it. However, when I earlier put my components onto one of the tabs of a *TabControl*, that was the behavior I found most intuitive. I wish to have a few sections (column-wise) and in each, one or more controls above each other. (Say, combox in the first one, three checkboxes in the second one, four radios in the third etc.) Is that sufficiently well described? I feel unsure.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Sounds like a `Grid` to me.